# Showing that sets of said type is Dedekind-infinite

Tags: set-theory

The problem I'm dealing with is the following.

> Show that every set $I$ which satisfies the conditions
>   $$\emptyset\in I,\quad (\forall x)[x\in I\Rightarrow\{x\}\in I]$$
>   is Dedekind-infinite.

Where Dedekind-infinite is defined as follows.

> A set is Dedekind-infinite if there exists an injection
>   $$f:A\rightarrow B\subset A$$
>   from A into a proper subset of itself.

My attempt to solve this was to construct a function
$$f(x):
\begin{cases}
x&\text{if } x\in R\subset I \\
\{x\}&\text{if } x\in I\backslash R
\end{cases}$$
where my thought was that I would map $R\subset I$ onto itself, and $I\backslash R$ onto something else. This doesn't fulfil the criteria as I must map all of $I$ injectively into $R$. Now I'm stuck with the thought that if I map something onto $R$ then I can't map more into $R$. Of course $I$ is infinite in size, but I don't know how to exploit this in order to obtain a satisfactory injection.

Comment: Actually the injection is very easy: simply consider $f(x)= \{ x\}$ (i.e. $R= \emptyset$).

Comment: @Crostul Mustn't $R$ be any subset of $I$ according to the definition? Also: $f(x)$ doesn't map every element of $I$ injectively into $R$. In fact it doesn't map any element into $R$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

$$f(x)=\{x\}$$

which is an injection from $I$ to $I\backslash\{\emptyset\}$. The function is well defined since $\forall x\left[x \in I \implies \{x\} \in I\right]$. $I\backslash\{\emptyset\}$ is a proper subset of $I$ since $\emptyset\in I$

Comment: I must be missing something obvious. Please observe my comment to Crostul!

Comment: I now see that the answer was obvious. My apologies. Thank you anyway!